# How Can I Update Encryption and Deffie Hellman Groups for VPN in GCP?

Tags: vpn, ipsec, encryption, gcp, google-cloud-vpn

So, I've got a VPN set up at the moment that's connected to the client's VPN and it's all good. Now, the client wants to tweak the encryption method to AES256 and Deffie Hellman groups to 19.

Is it doable? 'Cause I can't make those advanced changes through the GUI. Is there a way to make these tweaks in GCP?

As of now, I haven't run any tests because I'm not sure what steps to take. My concern is also whether, if the client makes these changes, will GCP automatically adjust and synchronize with the modifications made to the client's VPN?